# Get domain user from IPAddress or Hostname in .Net

Tags: c#, dns, growl

We're trying to implement a custom solution for Growl for Windows. We tell the Growl client to subscribe to notifications from our server. The server then gets a message from the client via the GNTP (Growl messaging protocol). We require the name of the user logged into the client machine in order to do database lookups. The GNTP does not provide this information.

So, we have a connected client socket (and thus, IP address) and a message from this client containing its machine name.

Is there any possible way to determine the username of the user who is logged into the specified machine? We have access to windows domain services.

Comment: After some more searching, it's clear that this isn't really doable. Is there a way to do the reverse? Get the IP or Host given the username?

Comment: Just to keep you on track: Yes, something like that should be possible - I've seen it at a customer. Give a username and you get the latest logins with machine names, which you could resolve to addresses. But I _think_ they do it with a global logon script. Can you do something like that? A logon script that calls http://yourserver/Login?Id=CurrentUser or something?

Comment: Why not have the client send the user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing the reverse (sorta) by having a client-side application run at logon and let our server know which user had logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the Windows domain and current user (if that's what you're after)

using System.Security.Principal;

```
        if (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string Result = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```